# Keep getting "Could not fetch toggles" with Unleash java sdk

Tags: java, spring-boot, gitlab, featuretoggle

I'm using unleash to implement feature toggles in my Spring Boot project and even though it works, I keep getting lots of `WARN` messages:

```
io.getunleash.UnleashException: Could not fetch toggles
    at io.getunleash.repository.HttpToggleFetcher.fetchToggles(HttpToggleFetcher.java:43)
    at io.getunleash.repository.FeatureToggleRepository.lambda$updateToggles$0(FeatureToggleRepository.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1059)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:791)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:726)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1688)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:529)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:308)
    at io.getunleash.repository.HttpToggleFetcher.getToggleResponse(HttpToggleFetcher.java:55)
    at io.getunleash.repository.HttpToggleFetcher.fetchToggles(HttpToggleFetcher.java:41)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
```

Is anyone having the same issue? Have no idea why I'm getting these warnings. Because after all, it's working fine other than this.